# YouTube v3 API returns comments not visible on web

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm attempting to get comments from YouTube, both through the web interface and the v3 API, but I'm having problems with (dis)agreement between the two sources.

One major issue I'm facing is that I frequently see comments in API results that don't appear when reading comments on the web.

For example, take a look at [this comment thread](https://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=H5Vzo-iPGCo&lc=z13ivlkotmmjgriuh23uxzjanmetidby004) (comment `z13ivlkotmmjgriuh23uxzjanmetidby004` on video `H5Vzo-iPGCo`) on the web, then compare this to API results from the following requests:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=replies&id=z13ivlkotmmjgriuh23uxzjanmetidby004&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

and

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=id%2Csnippet&parentId=z13ivlkotmmjgriuh23uxzjanmetidby004&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

In both cases the API returns the reply with id `z13ivlkotmmjgriuh23uxzjanmetidby004.1444155855551960`, which does not show up in the web UI. Also noteworthy here is that the web UI says "View all 10 replies," and then only displays nine.

I've encountered this on many comment threads (both replies and top-level comments, but mostly replies; most of them are too vulgar/offensive to include as examples here...), and I'm struggling to figure out what may be the cause of the invisible comments. Is there something in particular that causes this to occur? Is it indicative of something?

---

*Aside:* I've been working on this for several weeks at this point, and I've noticed that some of the comments exhibiting this behavior a few weeks ago no longer show up when searching with `part=replies` or with the `parentId` parameter, but still show up when searching for their `id` directly. Example, mild profanity included:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=id%2Csnippet&id=z121czphkmm1vhyy504cgxda3qfczhf4pi0.1428512050956459&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

vs.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=id%2Csnippet&parentId=z121czphkmm1vhyy504cgxda3qfczhf4pi0&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

---

The bottom line: I'd expect the API to give me the same comments as the web interface, but this often is not the case. Is there a logical reason or cause for the disagreements?

Comment: This could be a Google+ thing if the user commented on someone else's comment publicly, but decided to not make it public on their page anymore.

Comment: I've noticed something similar but opposite. This video has 3 public comments:

    https://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=-i6uOxl6Vdw

but the API only shows two of them:

    GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id%2Csnippet%2Creplies&textFormat=html&videoId=-i6uOxl6Vdw&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
    ....
    "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 2,
    ...